# How can I upload a (manually formed) csv String to Fusion Tables using Apps Script?

Tags: string, csv, google-apps-script, google-fusion-tables, media-type

I am trying to write an Apps Script to upload a csv string to a Fusion Table with the following code:

```
var txtCSV = 'my,csv,string';
var blbCSV = Utilities.newBlob(txtCSV);
FusionTables.Table.importRows(tableID, blbCSV);
```

I get the following error *"Media type 'text/plain' is not supported. Valid media types: [application/octet-stream]"*

Do I need to convert my csv string into a binary blob? If so, how do I do that ?
Or do I need to do it differently ?

Note: the csv string is constructed manually during previous steps within the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify the blob as an octet stream:

```
var txtCSV = 'my,csv,string'
var mediaData = Utilities.newBlob(txtCSV, 'application/octet-stream')
FusionTables.Table.importRows(TABLE_ID, mediaData)
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I thought I had tried something like that but I ran into conversion error, so obviously it wasn't what you wrote and wasn't good.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the prettiest solution, but I was finally able to make it work like so:

```
var txtCSV = 'my,csv,string';
var binCSV = Utilities.base64Decode(Utilities.base64Encode(txtCSV));
var blbCSV = Utilities.newBlob(binCSV);
FusionTables.Table.importRows(tableID, blbCSV);
```

Any suggestion is still welcome :-)